# How to deal with TIMEZONE in PostgreSQL's timestamptz

Tags: .net, postgresql, .net-core, utc

I have `Users` table with `birthdate` column of `timestamptz` type.
`TIMEZONE` in PostgreSQL is set to `UTC`.
I am setting `birthdate` in following way in code (.NET Core):

```
user.birthDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

What would happen if I would set `TIMEZONE` to `America\Los Angeles` and save my date (UTC representation from .NET code)? My `UTC` representation will be considered as `America\Los Angeles` and it will lead to invalid data representation?

Should I always keep `TIMEZONE` is set to `UTC`? Is it best practice for `timestamptz`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES says

> All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They
>   are converted to local time in the zone specified by the TimeZone
>   configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.

In your client code, you can change time zone parameter at session level; with timestamptz (timestamp with time zone) at database server level, there is nothing to change.

It is considered best pratice to use timestamp with timezone instead of timestamp without time zone: see https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/04/postgresql-data-types-date-timestamp-and-time-zones/#date-time-and-time-zones[enter link description here](https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/04/postgresql-data-types-date-timestamp-and-time-zones/#date-time-and-time-zones)